# XTerm Crash - Unable to open files

Tags: updates, files

I'm using Elementary OS 0.4 Loki. I updated my packages a few days ago and since then whenever I use "Files" to open a file I get an error:

**Failed to open files** Failed to execute child process "xterm" (No such file or directory)

How could I fix this error?

Comment: I update using sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade commands.

Comment: What kind of file do you want to open? Do you have the `xterm` package installed?

Comment: A text file. I don't know if I've any xterm packages installed. How could I check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to run `sudo apt install xterm` in a terminal window and test it again.

On the other hand, you might just want to change the way the file opens (as now it is set to be run with `xterm`), it depends on the file. You can do this with a right-click on the file you want to open and by selecting the application wanted under the `Open with` menu.